# Can Capybara select a checkbox or radio button within the scope of a specific field

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm using Capybara on a form that has multiple checkbox fields with an "Other" option.  The Capybara API gives us

```
page.check('Other')
```

but no way (that I can find) to limit the scope to a given ***field***.  You can limit the scope based on a CSS (or XPath) selector, but since none exist that make sense this requires that I either change the (ugly legacy) markup of the page just to accommodate Capybara, which seems like the wrong solution.  (In a perfect world I'd have time to completely refactor the markup, and wind up with something semantically sensible that also gave me a way of selecting a scope for Capybara, but this is not a perfect world, and I don't want to just jam in classes all of the place to accommodate Capybara.)

This

```
page.within('[name=FieldName]') do
  page.check('Other')
end
```

doesn't work, either, since Capybara is looking for a single parent node that it can use as the scope, and this gives a set of checkboxes.  (It would be nice if Capybara supported that, but it doesn't.)   It's like I'm passing a deck of cards to search through, and Capybara wants the box the cards go in, but I don't have any box.

I'd like to be able to do something like this

```
page.check('Other', :in => 'FieldName')
```

but I can't find anyway of doing that.  As far as I can tell, the only options that can be passed in are [`text`, `visible`, and `exact`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method).   Am I missing something?  Is there a way to do this without resorting to ugly workarounds?

Comment: Can you share the html of the page? It would help us to suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: The HTML is really ugly (and not mine!). The form is laid out in a table, and none of the table cells have ids or classes or anything else that would make a sensible selector.

Comment: Given you found a solution, there obviously is some sensible selector. But without at least a portion of the html (eg the input element), it would never have been possible for someone to come up with your solution (or alternatives).

Comment: @JustinKo: I don't think you understand: the selector I found is for the field itself, but the selector that Capybara's scoping system needs is for a *parent* of the field, in which it will search, and since no parent selector exists in CSS (at least as of CSS3) the fact that I found a selector for the field itself did not prove there's a selector to limit the scope.  If you were responsible for the hostile downvote, I don't think it is warranted.

Comment: @JustinKo: also, I would have been happy to provide the HTML for the field (although it wouldn't tell you much more than the fieldname and value, which I gave in generic form) but you asked for the entire page, which is gigantic and full or stuff that I probably can't disclose without violating my contract, and would be of little use anyway.  Couldn't you just trust me when I say it's laid out in tables with no ids or classes?

Comment: Sorry, I am obviously missing something. I thought the point was that the page has multiple "Other" checkboxes and you needed to locate a specific one. From that, I assumed that visually (to a human) there was some way of differentiating each of the checkboxes. If a human could differentiate the checkboxes, then I assumed (apparently incorrectly) that there must be something somewhere in the html that capybara could use. That is why I suggested sharing the html, which only had to be a portion that reproduced the problem (not everything).

Comment: Yes, but Capybara's scoping commands require a selector for a ***parent*** of the element you want to find.  I can easily differentiate between the "Other" checkboxes, but that didn't help for either the `.check` method (which doesn't take any options to specify field or selector) or the `.within`* methods (which require a parent of the field).   Your solution is a good one, as it gets around those limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a css-selector that can find the checkbox, you can use the `find` method to locate the checkbox.

```
page.find(:css, '[name=FieldName][value=Other]')
```

Then to check the checkbox, use `set` (which is used by the `check` method):

```
page.find(:css, '[name=FieldName][value=Other]').set(true)
```

You could also use the `click` method:

```
page.find(:css, '[name=FieldName][value=Other]').click
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant solution, but since no one is posting a better one (so far), here's the best I've come up with.

Just execute a script to do what you need.  In my case I'm using jQuery:

```
page.execute_script('$("[name=FieldName][value=Other]").trigger("click");')
```